# How to pass in additional parameters to sub class constructor?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

I implement the nodejs `Writable` class as below:

```
const { Writable } = require('stream');


class MyWriter extends Writable {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
 ...
```

according to the document I need to call `super(props)` in my writer constructor method. I wonder how I can pass in additional parameters in the constructor? 
If I define class let below how should I new the instance?

```
class MyWriter extends Writable {

        constructor(props, name) {
            super(props);
            this.name = name;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instatiate the MyWriter class as:

```
var myWriter = new MyWriter('props','name');
```

I think [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) link will help you.

Comment: If I can define parameters like this, why do I need to call `super(props)` in my class?

Comment: @ZhaoYi - You have to call the base constructor with `super(...)` so it can initialize its part of the object and you have to pass it the arguments it is expecting.  You are free to make the constructor arguments for the derived object anything you want as long as you call the base constructor with whatever arguments it is expecting.